# How to run and work with Node.js on my remote VPS

Tags: node.js, deployment

Maybe it is dummy or noob question, but this is the first time I am trying to run / deploy my local Node.js application to the internet via my VPS hosting.

When working locally, I am using nodemon package to auto restart the server on each change.
Also, when turn off the terminal or shut down the Mac, the Node.js will be shut down too.

How these things could be handled via a remote VPS with a public domain?

Btw, another thing is how to compress/compile/hide/secure my client side code so it wont be able to be read or something.
I am asking this because when I am doing source code, It is very clear to see the whole app requests and therefore "play" with this.

Thanks.

Comment: you should try to use `pm2` or `forever` to start your application, when you close your terminal on your mac, you just killed the application on your remote vps. `pm2` can keep your app alive after you close your terminal.

Comment: Sound good I will try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out pm2 (production node manager)
you can install like this

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

so instead of nodemon app.js you'll run

```
pm2 start app.js
```

instead. This keeps your app running even if you restart your server
check out the [official site for more info on pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

Comment: Very nice. May I do the same with MongoDB?

pm2 start mongod ?

Comment: Nah, I'll advice you use external providers like https://mlab.com or mongodb atlas

Comment: Is it not recomment to work with MongoDB on my own VPS?
Should I use "two" servers for one project?
One server hosts files and another remote server hosts MongoDB?

Comment: You can but its not advisable in production if you really hope to scale

Comment: I use mlab and it's cheap, you dont need to pay if the db is not that large or the platform is not yet performing

Comment: What do you mean to scale?
My VPS is also cloud so it is also able to be scaled, or that this is not what you meaned?

Comment: i mean when you get high traffic and patronage that you didn't speculate you might not be able to handle it with a single server. And besides mlab or atlas performs better for db

Comment: Those services you mentioned, do it automatically?